# Debugging Win Mobile 6 App with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

When I go in to debug the app, it asks me to choose where I would like to deploy it. When I select Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional Emulator and click the Deploy button, it starts to work and throws up a command line and then it goes away and Visual Studio doesn't appear to be in debug mode.

I have the Device Emulator open, Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional Emulator loaded and cradled. Can someone help me figure out why it will not let me debug this project?

Comment: Visual Sudio 2007? Is it not VS2005 or 2008? Despite from that confusion we do not know how to debug 'this project' without having a copy. There are so many settings that may disable the debug. Did you alreday try a new project by simply following the New Project Wizard? BTW: you leave no word about what programming language you use etc. Please provide more details if you need help.

Comment: Sorry, it is VS 2008 using C#. I just created a new project added a text box and then went to Tools -> Device Emulator Manager and then right clicked on Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional Emulator and clicked connect and then cradle. Then I went to Debug -> Start Debugging and there is no Windows Mobile 6.5.3 option. I went into the project settings and then clicked on Devices and in the "Target Device" there is no Windows Mobile 6.5.3 option but it is in the emulator which I am guessing is the problem. Is there something else to download and install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brad, I downloaded the code and just unpacked the zip to D:\boxoffice_mobile (a local drive partition). Then I started VisualStudio 2008 and opened the solution file. I get a warning message that the project is not loaded from a trusted location (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2bkwxc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). As I do not use a network drive, I ignored the warning two times and the projects load all fine.

BTW: I found a great tool to manage these 'security' warnings: http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2010/03/05/the-project-location-is-not-trusted-dealing-with-the-dreaded-unblock/. The message had nothing to do with a remote file access.

Then I just looked at the solution configuration to ensure that only the needed projects are build and did no change, as only BoxOfficeMobile and WebserviceTest are set to build and only BoxOfficeMobile is set to deploy.

Then closed solution configuration manager and just pressed F5 to start debugging to see what happens.

The startup project BoxOfficeMobile was build and deployed to "Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional Emulator". The emulator started and the files were deployed and the project was stopped by a breakpoint inside the code:

[image]

Here is another screen shot with the emulator set to 'Display: Always on top':

[image]

So, as you can see, the project is fine and the debug issue on your site is caused by a different setup.

Do you load the project from a network drive share? Try moving it to a local drive and run it from there.

Did you change Device settings in the VS2008 Tools:Options menu? Here is my setup (as coming as default, I did not change anything):

[image: Tools:Options:Device Tools]

and the details:

[image: Device Properties]

The additional settings available via the buttons are empty (Configure) or unchanged (Emulator Options).

I am very interested in seeing what you changed to be not able to debug the project.

Comment: I have no clue, I extracted the zip that I sent you (and I was not loading from a network drive) and it loaded right up and I was able to debug it. Cause you went through all the details of this I will accept your error. I am not sure what changed on my system to cause it to start debugging...... VERY ODD

Comment: Yes, very strange. Possibly the zip does not contain all files (ie hidden files or additional streams) and therefor your unpacked new directory works.The error message I got is a security feature and comes up when Windows detects files that have been created on another computer. No matter, glad to hear you are able to debug now.

Answer (score 0):

before you start developing for Windows Mobile 6.5 Prof, you need to setup your development environment.

First, install Visual Studio 2008 (no express version)

Download and install either [ActiveSync](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15) (host OS <= Windows XP) or Windows Mobile Device Center / [WMDC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14) (Windows Vista/7)

[optional] Download and install [Device Emulator Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5352)

Then download and install Windows Mobile 6.5 DTK (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389)

Now, you can start a new C# project inside Visual Studio 2008:
[image]

Follow the wizard:
[image]

The list of Target Platforms depend on the Mobile/CE SDKs you have installed!

Select either .Net Compact Framework 2.0 or 3.5. The choose depends on what is installed on your PC and what is available on the device. If the device comes with 2.0 pre-installed, I would choose 2.0 except for I need something only available in 3.5 (ie Mobile.Status namespace).

Now you get an empty form:
[image]

You can change the target device in the project properties:
[image]

If you want to change the target platform, look at "Change Target Platform" in Project menu or just right click the project in solution explorer and select Change Target Platform:
[image]

The above has nothing to do with Device Emulator Manager or the installed Emulator Images!

You can run a WM5 targeting project on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device if you want.

**To start debugging and SmartDevice application inside an emulator. Just Select an Emulator entry from the target device list in Project properties or just in the SmartDevice toolbar. Then click Debug and "Start Debugging". VS will start an emulator with the specified emulator image and deploys your project application files and start remote devugging.**

You may also start an emulator image using DeviceEmulatorManager and then cradle the running Emulator image. To use the running and cradled (ActiveSync or WMDC connected!) emulator do NOT select an emulator inside VS but a Device. VS does not see the difference and uses the WMDC connected device, regardless of being an emulator or real device.

VS uses DMA to communicate with the emulator, not USB or Serial as with a real device.

Now start your development.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information but I can still not debug this project. If I create a new project I am able to debug it fine in the emulator. I went into the project I am trying to debug and switched it to the target platform "Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK" tried to debug and still wouldnt work so then I went and changed it back to "Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK" and tried to debug again and was still unable.

So I can debug a new project, but I cant debug my existing project.

Comment: Start two instances of VS and load one with the new 'debug OK' and one with your non-working project. Then compare the project settings side by side. Possibly a debug settings is wrong or the target platform or ...Without having the project on my PC I cannot say what is wrong exactly. Everything else is only guessing and time wasting. You may even start a new project and then copy all code from the old to the new project. O do you have any further information (error messages, debug or build console output)?

Comment: There are no errors being displayed in the debug window (where it shows errors when its being compiled). Is there another place where it would output messages like to a log file or something like that where I could look?

Comment: Here is the link to Download the Source Code [Download Source](http://www.stubwire.com/_temp/boxoffice_mobile.zip)

Answer (score 0):

First of all clean your project.Then freshly start the emulator.Right click the project and select build.Then Debug the project.Your project will be started in Emulator (Don't Open the application from your Emulator at this time).
Just check your Emulator Start>File Explorer>My Device>Program Files whether the project has been previously installed.If so uninstall from the Settings> System > Remove Programs. And try re-building application and deploy it.